# Can make figure out file dependencies in AWS S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3, makefile, aws-cli

The source directory contains numerous large image and video files.

These files need to be uploaded to an AWS S3 bucket with the `aws s3 cp` command. For example, as part of this build process, I copy my image file `my_image.jpg` to the S3 bucket like this: `aws s3 cp my_image.jpg  s3://mybucket.mydomain.com/`

I have no problem doing this copy to AWS manually. And I can script it too. But I want to use the makefile to upload my image file `my_image.jpg` ***iff*** the same-named file in my S3 bucket is older than the one in my source directory.

Generally `make` is very good at this kind of dependency checking based on file dates. However, is there a way I can tell `make` to get the file dates from files in S3 buckets and use that to determine if dependencies need to be rebuilt or not?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `sync`, rather than `cp`?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples

Comment: Mike. I was unaware of the sync command/. I think I can use it to satisfy my needs. Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct so you can be awarded the points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AWS CLI has an `s3 sync` command that can take care of a fair amount of this for you.  From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

> A s3 object will require copying if:
>
> - the sizes of the two s3 objects differ,
> - **the last modified time of the source is newer than the last modified time of the destination**,
> - or the s3 object does not exist under the specified bucket and prefix destination.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to make S3 look like a file system to make this work. On Linux it is common to use [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to build adapters like that. [Here](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) [are](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) [some](https://github.com/danilop/yas3fs) projects to present S3 as a local filesystem. I haven't tried any of those, but it seems like the way to go.